# Decompress column data using Hive UDF

Tags: java, hive, udf, compression

**Context:** 
**Decompress the column data using Hive UDF evaluate() method**

**Exception:**

> Failed with exception 
>   java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   Unable to execute method public static org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
>   Test.UDFDecompressor.evaluate(java.lang.String) throws
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException  on object
>   Test.UDFDecompressor@1008df1e of class Test.UDFDecompressor with
>   arguments
>   {xï¿½ï¿½}kwâ¸²ï¿½_aï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ö¤ï¿½\ï¿½ï¿½a-Bï¿½iï¿½@`ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½"ï¿½nc3ï¿½Iï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½$_ï¿½Eï¿½ï¿½
>   } of size 1

**Source Code:**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.JavaStringObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory;

public class Decompress extends UDF{
public static String evaluate(String data1) throws IOException, DataFormatException{
ByteArrayInputStream bao=new ByteArrayInputStream(data1.getBytes());
InflaterInputStream iis= new InflaterInputStream(bao);
String out="";
byte[] bt=new byte[1024];
int len=-1;
while ((len =iis.read(bt))!=-1){ 
out += new String(Arrays.copyOf(bt, len));
}
JavaStringObjectInspector stringInspector;
stringInspector = PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector;
String ip = stringInspector.getPrimitiveJavaObject(out);

//return new String(ip.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
//return new String(ip.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
return ip;
}
}
```

I tried multiple ways to decompress using gZib,zLIb Java Api but am facing the same error. Can anyone help me out in resolving this issue and suggest right approach to decompress the column data using **Hive UDF**

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream;

public class Decompress extends UDF {

    private final Text r = new Text();

    public Text evaluate(BytesWritable bw) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayInputStream zipped = new ByteArrayInputStream(bw.getBytes());
        InflaterInputStream inflater = new InflaterInputStream(zipped);
        ByteArrayOutputStream unzipped = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] bt = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = inflater.read(bt)) != -1) {
            unzipped.write(bt, 0, len);
        }

        r.clear();
        r.set(unzipped.toByteArray());
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This answer may be a better way to do what the original poster is trying to do, but they have specifically asked for an explanation of what they were doing wrong.  This isn't that.  It's not going to help them learn for next time, which is a big part of Stack Overflow. Can you add some commentary on what they're doing wrong, and why you recommend this approach instead?